# How to I scrape images from a list of urls and download it to local folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib

I am iterating through a list of urls for images.

```py
import requests

list_url = ["www.abc.com/def.jpg", " www.abc.com/def1.jpg",... "www.abc.com/def100000.jpg"]

correct_img_list = []

for img in list_url:

    request = requests.get(img)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        correct_img_list.append(img)
        continue
    else:
        continue
i = 1 

for img in correct_img_list:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, "local_image file_" + str(i))
    i += 1
```

I want it to go through the list, grab the url and then download the image to a local directory.

The error that i am  seeing is this :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/liuh9/Desktop/google chrome folder/image-downloader.py", line 714, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, "local_image file " + str(i))
  File "C:\Users\liuh9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\liuh9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\liuh9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\liuh9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\liuh9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\liuh9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\liuh9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: It seems like the image URL does not exist. Are you sure that all the URLs in the list work? If so, then you should print the URL before calling the URLretrieve, to make sure you are retrieving the right url

Comment: @chatax how would i get the http status of the url

Comment: You could just visit the URL in your browser. I would run your code and print the requested URL before the URL retrieve. Than try to visist the URL that gave you the 404 not found

Comment: for img in list_url:
    
    request = requests.get(img)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        continue
    else:
        print(img)
        print('Web site does not exist') 
        list_url.remove(img)

Comment: What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 1):

The response code you got is 404, which indicates that the URL does not exist.

As a good practice make sure that you check the response code and do further operations only when response code is 200. I would also recommend adding the operations in a try except block so that the program does not crash on the first invalid URL.

Look at below example

```
import urllib.request


url_list = ["https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/07/11/37/tropical-1651426__340.jpg", "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/long-exposure-soft-colorful-sunset-260nw-142504771.jpg"]
filename = 1

for url in url_list:
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, f'{filename}.jpg')
        filename += 1
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f"Exception occued while downloading image from url {url} {str(exc)}")
```

Comment: for img in list_url:
    
    request = requests.get(img)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        continue
    else:
        print(img)
        print('Web site does not exist') 
        list_url.remove(img)